# access referenced images model from projects model in laravel

Tags: slider, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8

-1

I have made 2 models:

Project model -

```
   
    public function project()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Gallery::class, 'project_id' , 'id');
    }
```

Gallery model -

```
 public function galle()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Projects::class, 'id' , 'project_id');
    }
```

I want to display image gallery for each project, I have made a foreign key in images table that references projects table and i want to access all the images for a specific project and display it in my view

here are the pictures of my db tables:

Gallery table

Project table

pagecontroller -

```
  
    public function viewProject($slug)
    {
        $gallery  = Gallery::get();
        $projectview = Projects::where('slug', $slug)->get();
        return view('web.project-child', compact('projectview','gallery'));
    }
```

blage.php -

```
  @foreach ($gallery as $gal)
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 project-gal-image">
                  <img src="{{ asset(''.$gal->gallery_image) }}" alt="First slide" data-target="#carouselExample" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

this is the question anyone can help me fort this..

Comment: `$gallery  = Gallery::find();` should be triggering the error *"Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::find(), 0 passed [...] and at least 1 expected"*. Is this your actual, working code?

Comment: public function viewProject($slug)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::get();
        $projectview = Projects::where('slug', $slug)->get();
        return view('web.project-child', compact('projectview','gallery'));
    }
this is the code I forgot to add get()

Comment: I really want to display image gallery for each project, I have made a foreign key in galleries table that references projects table.. if any other way have to do this can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your relationship methods to match the relationship they represent:

```
class Project ...
{
    ...
    public function galleries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Gallery::class);
    }
}

class Gallery ...
{
    ...
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

Your Controller method can be simplified if you also use [Implicit Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) starting with the route definition:

```
Route::get('project/{project:slug}', ...);
```

Controller:

```
public function view(Project $project)
{
    return view(..., ['project' => $project]);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($project->galleries as $gallery)
    {{ $gallery->gallery_image }}
@endforeach
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing - Route Model Binding - Implicit Binding - Customizing The Key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-key)